# Calculator gives the solution of "$10^2+(10i)^2$" as "$1.22464679914735\times10^{-14}i$" instead of zero. Why?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, calculator

Now solving on pen and paper as well as online calculators including wolfram alpha gives the result as 0 as expected. But using a [calculator on android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scientificCalculator) gives the solution as $1.22464679914735\times10^{-14}i$.
I am attaching the picture. Can anyone explain what is going on?
[take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUxnf.jpg)

Edit: Thanks for the edit Chase

Comment: Welcome to the wonders of floating-point arithmetic!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Other calcs give zero. Is this particular calculator faulty?

Comment: What happens when you enter the expression as 10*10 + (10i)*(10i) instead?

Comment: @Ted Huh, It now gives zero. :-o

Comment: Based on that, it's likely that it's implementing the power operation (maybe only in the case of complex numbers) x^2 as exp(2 log(x)).  This would introduce a bunch of intermediate floating point operations into what looks like a simple integer calculation, thus causing rounding error. I'm a little surprised that it would happen for numbers this small, though.

Comment: Thank you @Ted I will keep this in mind before trusting a calc blindly

Comment: As a demonstration, in python (using the math or numpy module for complex functions) the execution of `np.exp(2*np.log(10))+np.exp(2*np.log(10j))` results in `1.2246467991473537e-14j`.

Comment: Try typing tan(pi/2) into some calculators as well.

Comment: @kingW3 I just did. It is definitely not undefined. Oh boy, it is getting harder to trust calculators. :-(

Comment: The lesson to be learned here is not to throw away all calculators, but to be aware of such issues when using them. The common theme is: if you rely on a number being *exactly* some value for a calculation to be correct (like x/x is undefined only if x is *exactly* 0, in your comment below, or tan(x) is undefined if x is exactly pi/2 but not for values close to pi/2), then you could run into these problems because rounding errors may happen.  And if you ever see an unexplainable small number like the one in the title of this post, it should be a sign to look at things more closely.

Comment: Aye @Ted Your comment makes sense. And I agree. As for my earlier comments they were only my attempts at levity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 1.22464679914735*10^(-14)i is so small it is basically zero. I have experienced this myself, and I was told that some calculators tend to display an extremely small number instead of zero. If you round 1.22464679914735*10^(-14)i you do get 0 as a result.

You can find an interesting article about this [here](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/?eu=true) (it is useful in your case even though it uses Excel as an example).

Comment: Then if i divide 10^2+(10i)^2 by itself I will get 1. But I should have gotten undefined when divided. So (10^2+(10i)^2)/(10^2+(10i)^2) should be 1 or undefined?

Comment: So I should just ignore the non-zero number and consider it as zero which will by definition lead to undefined when divided. Right?

Comment: My theory is that perhaps the calculator doesn't evaluate the two expressions in this case, the result should be 1. And yes, when you get that super small non-zero number you should ignore it and consider the result undefined if you divide. You can read even more on the topic [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Floating-PointArithmetic.html) if you're interested.

Answer (score 6):

The calculator is nothing but a computer program. Some may be programmed to recognize the integer exponent. But others, like the one you used, probably used a general formula like $x^y=\exp (y\log x) $. This was performed using floating point arithmetic and errors are unavoidable since $\log10$ is irrational.

Comment: Got it @Martin. This problem was confusing me for days.